# Mulesoft combine 3 query results into one payload

Tags: transform, anypoint-studio, mulesoft, payload

I have a results from a parent table, a child table and a relation table. I need to merge the three tables together based on the values in the relation table using "ParentId" and "ChildId". I have tried to use Scatter Gather in AnyPoint Studio and can get results for each query but I am having trouble combining them back into one payload so that the parent, relationship values and child are all on same line.
Parents can have move than one child.

Payloads are based on queries from Salesforce tables -

Payload Object 0:

```
Array<object>:
 [
{"ParentId": "0cE3S0000000HVGUA2", 
 "Name": "job's Pharmacy"
 "Address": "123 4th Ave", 
 "ParentLicense": "PHARM.PF.12345678"}
]
```

Payload Object 1:

```
Array<Object>:
[
{ "ChildId": "0cE3S0000000GscUAE", 
 "ParentId": 0cE3S0000000HVGUA2, 
 "RelationStatus":"Site Branch"}
]
```

Payload Object 2:

```
Array<Object>:
[
{ "ChildId": "0cE3S0000000GscUAE", 
 "ChildLicense": PHRM.PF.98765432-MHOUT, 
"ExpirationDate": "2019-02-28",
"PublicStatusDescription": "Closed"}
]
```

Expected Result

```json
[
 {
  "ParentId": "0cE3S0000000HVGUA2", 
  "Name": "job's Pharmacy"
  "Address": "123 4th Ave", 
  "ParentLicense": "PHARM.PF.12345678",
  "ChildId": "0cE3S0000000GscUAE", 
  "ChildLicense": PHRM.PF.98765432-MHOUT, 
  "ExpirationDate": "2019-02-28",
  "PublicStatusDescription": "Closed", 
  "RelationStatus":"Site Branch"
 }
]
```

Comment: Are the tables coming from database queries inside your application?

Comment: Please edit the question to add details.

Comment: Where do you put those objects in the application? something in the payload and the other two in variables?

Comment: Not quite sure what you are asking.  the payloads are derived from scatter gather subflow queries via transform messages with an anypoint project.

Comment: Ok, an example simple payload would be useful if you want a literal answer.

Comment: I added the objects

Comment: It would have been better if you used the payload as is instead of showing separate snippets. I had to guess how to pierce it together assuming it is the output of a scatter-gather.

Answer (score 0):

If the data comes from SQL queries from the same database and inside the same application it is better to use SQL to get the data already joined. SQL will be more efficient and it is basically designed to do it.

If the data comes from a different source, like different REST APIs, then you can use DataWeave to join the data.

Note that for simplicity I use JSON as the output format, but you should use application/java if you intend to do further transformations.

This is an example. Probably it is not the most efficient way to do it:

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
import * from dw::core::Arrays
var parents=payload."0"
var childs=payload."2"
var relation=payload."1"
var parentWithChildId=leftJoin(parents, relation, (p) -> p.ParentId, (r) -> r.ParentId)
    map((item, index) -> item.l ++ {ChildId: item.r.ChildId})
var parentWithChildValues=leftJoin(parentWithChildId, childs, (p) -> p.ChildId, (c) -> c.ChildId)
    map((item, index) -> item.l ++ (item.r - "ChildId"))
---
parentWithChildValues
```

Input: I had to guess how the input should look assuming it is the output of a scatter-gather.

```json
{
    "0": 
        [
            {
                "ParentId": "0cE3S0000000HVGUA2", 
                "Name": "job's Pharmacy",
                "Address": "123 4th Ave", 
                "ParentLicense": "PHARM.PF.12345678"
            }
        ],
    "1":
        [
            {
                "ChildId": "0cE3S0000000GscUAE", 
                "ParentId": "0cE3S0000000HVGUA2", 
                "RelationStatus":"Site Branch"
            }
        ],
    "2":
        [
            { 
                "ChildId": "0cE3S0000000GscUAE", 
                "ChildLicense": "PHRM.PF.98765432-MHOUT", 
                "ExpirationDate": "2019-02-28",
                "PublicStatusDescription": "Closed"
            }
        ]
}
```

Output:

```json
[
  {
    "ParentId": "0cE3S0000000HVGUA2",
    "Name": "job's Pharmacy",
    "Address": "123 4th Ave",
    "ParentLicense": "PHARM.PF.12345678",
    "ChildId": "0cE3S0000000GscUAE",
    "ChildLicense": "PHRM.PF.98765432-MHOUT",
    "ExpirationDate": "2019-02-28",
    "PublicStatusDescription": "Closed"
  }
]
```

Comment: The data is within salesforce so no way to combine the tables as in SQL

Comment: Depending if you are using SOQL or not you could do something similar, or you can just go with a method similar to what I mentioned.

Comment: I have added an example of the data names above in the question, can you provide me an example using those values, I'm very literal.  Thank  you